# Getting HTTP error 500 even if the account is authorised

Tags: html, mysql, cpanel

Having an issue with the database enabling on my cpanel.

I am using A2Hosting.

As I create the tables I get this error when I go to a page that uses it:

[image: 1]

To try and fix this I added privileges to my account

[image: 2]

here is my database code:

```
<?php

class config_db {

  public function init() {
PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname="DATABASENAME";charset=utf8', '"USERNAME"', '"PASSWORD"');

    return $db;
  }

}

?>
```

After adding privileges I get this error:

[image: 3]

Not sure why I still get an HTTP ERROR 500 after I have granted privileges

---

**UPDATE:**

As I checked one solution is to delete the plugins, but my cpanel files has none of it

**UPDATE:**

Creating a username and password that the database uses uniquely does not work either

**UPDATE:**

Deleting the .htaccess folder gets me a 404 not found problem

**UPDATE:**

There are no errors shown using inspect element or event in the cpanel

[image: 5]

**UPDATE:**

The database is connected succesfully as I checked but the error 500 still persists

[image: 6]

Comment: Which cpannel you are using... from hostgator? do confirm the hostname... does this on same server?

Comment: my cpanel is a2hosting, will update it too in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In A2Hosting please make sure you are using the correct database name. As per the documentation it should be:

When you create a database, your username is **prefixed** to the database name.

For example, if your username is **abc**, and you create a database named **db**, the actual MySQL database name is **abc_db**.

For more information: 
https://www.a2hosting.com/kb/cpanel/cpanel-database-features/managing-mysql-databases

Comment: the thing is in my server theres another site with a database that workds absolutely fine, im just baffled why this one has the error

Comment: i added a few more updates, testing what i can to try and fix the issue

Comment: @HadrianClayton first of all make sure the credentials are correct... are you able to use this db credentials from other site on the same server?

Comment: yes i tried it with the same user that is connected to a db of another site that works

Comment: @Hadrian just confirm, you have checked same user credentials + same db + same server only the site is different?

Comment: yes credentials are the same, but the database is different, for the current site im trying to make it work.

Comment: @HadrianClayton can you please mark this? if it helps to solve your issue.